# Using Prolog Lists in Recursion

Tags: list, recursion, path, prolog

So I am trying to use a recursive method to find a path between two people. Here is the quick background:
I define some facts `in(X,Y)`. That show who is related, ie. `in(person1,project1)`, `in(person2,project1)`, etc etc. Now any two people are related if they were in the same project as each other, or there is a linking path of people between them. For example p1 worked on A p2 worked on A and B and p3 worked on B therefore there is a path from p1 to p3 through p2. These paths can be any length.

I am trying to solve this recursively (don't see any other way), but there is an annoying problem:

```
related(A,B) :-
        in(A,X),
        in(B,X),
        not(A=B).

chain(A,B) :-
        related(A,B).
chain(A,B) :-
        related(A,Y),       
        chain(Y,B).
```

The issue is that the path can repeat itself. It can go from p1 to p2 back to p1 endless times. A person should not be in the path more than 1 time.

I tried to fix this with a list that I add to. If a person is already in the list, they can't be added again:

```
related(A,B,L) :-
        in(A,X),
        in(B,X),not(A=B).

chain(A,B,L) :-
        related(A,B,L).
chain(A,B,L) :-
        related(A,Y,L),
        not(member(Y,L)),
        append(L,[Y],Q),
        chain(Y,B,Q).
```

And it sort of worked, but caused a ton of random errors, repeating some people multiple times, some only once, and then failing. Does this approach look right? Am I totally using lists wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was never perfectly clear enough, but I ended up solving this myself. I put the code below.

What really mattered was an effective notchain predicate and then making sure I did the appends correctly. I also created a notsame predicate to replace the not(A=B). The code is below. Most of the answer was making sure that there were [] around what was being appended to the list. Not having the correct [] around what was being appended caused errors.

> notchain(X,L) :-
>
> member(X,L),!,fail.
>
> notchain(X,L).

And then:

> chain(A,B,L) :-
>
> related(A,B),
>        append(L,[A],Q),
>        append(Q,[B],Z),
>        write(final),writeln(Z).
>
> chain(A,B,L) :-
>         notchain(A,L),
>         append(L,[A],Q),
>         related(A,Y),
>           chain(Y,B,Q).

This was used in related:

> notsame(A,B) :-
>     (A=B),!,fail.
>
> notsame(A,B).

Answer (score 0):

First improvement. Are you looking for all the chains of relations or do you want to check if there is one chain of relation? In the first case add a cut.

```
chain(A,B) :-
        related(A,B), !.
chain(A,B) :-
        related(A,Y),       
        chain(Y,B).
```

In the second case, Prolog does exactly what it's asked to do, that is finding all the possible chains.

Please post a query that causes problems so that we can reason together on it and improve the solution.

Comment: All the chains is preferable. The real problem is that a chain can have the same person in it multiple times, there needs to be a way to prevent that. I will post sample output later when I am home.

I know how to do this easily in Java, C, C#, etc but prolog is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way, maybe less efficient but rather general, based on fixpoint computation.

```
connected(Found, Connected) :-
    collect(Found, [], Ext),
    (   Ext == Found
    ->  Connected = Found
    ;   connected(Ext, Connected)
    ).

collect([], Set, Set).
collect([E|Es], Set, Fix) :-
    extend(E, Set, Ext),
    collect(Es, Ext, Fix).

extend(E, Set, Ext) :-
    directly(E, DirectConn),
    ord_union(DirectConn, Set, Ext).

directly(A, DirectConn) :-
    setof(B, P^(in(A, P), in(B, P)), DirectConn).
```

We must call connected(Found, Connected) with a sorted list, and it loops until the set cannot be extended. For instance, with this test data

```
in(anna,  project1).
in(bob,   project1).
in(bob,   project2).
in(chris, project2).
in(dan,   project3).

?- connected([bob],L).
L = [anna, bob, chris].

?- connected([dan],L).
L = [dan].
```

I allow on purpose directly/2 get identity, i.e.

```
?- directly(X,Y).
X = anna,
Y = [anna, bob] ;
...
X = dan,
Y = [dan].
```