# Infinite Loop caused by Append?

Tags: loops, recursion, prolog, infinite

I have a bit of a question regarding *why* my code seems to hang when I run it.  The code is for a project I have in a class, but we spent one class period going over Prolog so much of what I've learned is stuff I've searched around for and have taught myself.  I do apologize if my code contains horrendous stylistic errors, but again, as we never formally learned how we 'should' use Prolog, this is based mostly on my own experimentation.

The goal of the segment of code I am writing is, more or less, to form a chain that connects one actor to another through a series of movies that they have been in.

I have a function I am calling that is meant to construct connections between a starting actor, all possible linked actors ending actor, and the list of movies that connects them.  This is probably a horribly inefficient method of doing this, however implementing it this way solves two parts of the assignment with one segment of code.

The code that calls the function works, and for the sake of making this simpler to read, I will omit it unless asked to share it.  In short, it asserts a `globalStartingActor`, and passes on two empty lists (`ActorList = []` and `MovieList = []`) to a function `doActorAssertions`.

In turn, we have `doActorAssertions`.  This is the revised version of it, which should be simplified and easier to read, but lacks the massive commenting that it had previously.

```
doActorAssertions(ActorsName,ActorList,MovieList) :-
    isNotInList(ActorsName,ActorList) ->
    (
        findMoviesIn(ActorsName,MoviesIn),%finds all movies ActorsName is in
        howLong(MoviesIn,LenMoviesIn),%Sees how many movies there are.
        (
            LenMoviesIn ==0;
            (
                append(ActorsName,ActorList,UpdatedActorList),%this causes errors!
                globalStartingActor(GSAName),%asserted starting actor
                assert(connectedActors(GSAName,ActorsName,MovieList)), %says that the GSAName is connected to ActorsName by a list of movies MovieList.
                write(actorAsserted),               
                addAndTraverse(MoviesIn,UpdatedActorList,MovieList) %Goes to propegate all movies the actor is in, then actors in those movies, then recursively calls this function again.     
            )
        )
    ),
    true.
```

As I said previously, the `append` tag seemed to be the source of the error!  This indeed appears to be the case when I simplify the code to what it is above.  I simply comment that append out, and the code body works.

Why, then, is append preventing the code from working properly?  I need to have append (or similar function) in that part of the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ActorsName` a list? The variable' name suggests it is, as well as the usage in append/3, but then what `isNotInList(ActorsName,ActorList)` means? Partial or full disjunction? This could be the cause of the endless loop, maybe you should use the difference of those sets to increment the ActorList.

You should try to avoid assert/1, and instead pass around the state in variables. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204498/874024) for a schema doing something very similar to what you are attempting here.

This is useless, could be a typo, but then I don't understand the `->`

```
  ...
  ),
  true.
```

I think should read

```
  ...
  );     % note the semicolon!
  true.
```

Comment: Ugh.  Comments can only be edited for five minutes, what dark magic is this?  

ActorsName is basically the same as "Actor's Name" - it is a singular 'string," not a list. isNotInList is basically a negation of 'memberof/member,' which takes one item and a list as parameters.

The semicolon at the end -- I don't see why I didn't have it there in the first place. Good catch, thanks!

Yes, I figured that assertions would not be the prettiest way of doing things.    I will take a look at the link you have shared as well.

Comment: Okay, so I took a look at the append again - as you mentioned that ActorsName suggests that it should be a list.  I changed append to being append([ActorsName],ActorList,UpdatedActorList), and it appears to have resolved the error.  Thank you for pointing that out; I figured I could get away with appending non-list stuff to a list, as I do all the time in most programming languages!